# Get SOQL Query to get Account's Name Instead of the Id?

Tags: apex, soql

When I try to manually query using:

```
SELECT Account.Name, Name FROM Contact
```

I am getting the Account Name

When I put it inside an apex class

```
    String likeParam = '%' + searchParam+'%';
    String Query = 'SELECT Account.Name, Name FROM Contact Where Name Like : likeParam LIMIT 10';
    List<sObject> sObjectList = Database.query(Query);
    return sObjectList;
```

I am getting the record id instead of the name.

Any ideas? I think it's connected with **Database.Query**

Apex is controlling the Lightning Component that I created.

Result from query:
[image]

Result from lightning component:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Is this part of a test class? One explanation for this result would be that you have inserted a test account without a name, Salesforce will then automatically fill the field with the account id, and that may be how you now get this result.

Comment: Please show us the actual code that is being used to display the data.

Comment: Thank you both for the response I updated my post to add more context.

Comment: `003` is the key prefix for Contact, not Account. There is something completely different wrong in your Lightning component code.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look at my component. Now I know that the query is not the source of the problem

Comment: @DavidReed I got it now, I'm using `{!item.Id}` in my component instead of `{!item.Account.Name}` please post your answer so I can mark it as best answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`003` is the key prefix for a Contact Id, not an Account Id. This indicates that the issue lies, as you mentioned in comments, that the problem lies in Lightning component code or markup, rather than in the SOQL/Apex layer.