# Dynamic SOQL gives Id in LWC datable instead of object Name even using __r.Name

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql, javascript

I need a big help with my LWC Component, I'm using Dynamic SOQL but I need to show the Name of lookup field and even using __r it shows Id, here is my codes and the view :

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static String getRelatedFieldsAndRecords(String negotiationId){
        Map<String, String> returnMap = new Map<String,String>();

        //get fields from FieldSet
        SObject sObj = (SObject)(Type.forName('Schema.'+ 'CLM_Representative__c').newInstance());
        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> lstFSMember = sObj.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fieldSets.getMap().get('CLM_Representative').getFields();

        //prepare SOQL query based on fieldAPIs 
        String query = 'SELECT ';
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : lstFSMember) {
            if(f.getFieldPath() == 'CLM_Account__c' || f.getFieldPath() == 'CLM_Contact__c') {
                String str = f.getFieldPath().Substring(0,f.getFieldPath().length()-1);
                query += str + 'r.Name, ';
            } 
            else 
            {
                query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
            }
        }

        query += 'Id FROM ' + 'CLM_Representative__c' ;
        query += ' WHERE CLM_Negotiation__c = ' + '\'' + negotiationId + '\'';

        //execute query
        List<CLM_Representative__c > lstRecords = Database.query(query);

        String JSONStringRecords = JSON.serialize(lstRecords);

        //prepare a map which will hold fieldList and recordList and return it
        returnMap.put('FIELD_LIST', JSON.serialize(lstFSMember));
        returnMap.put('RECORD_LIST', JSONStringRecords);

        return JSON.serialize(returnMap);
    }
```

JS:

```
connectedCallback(){
        getFieldsAndRecords({   strObjectApiName: 'Contact',
                                strfieldSetName: 'CLM_Legal_Representative',
                                negotiationId: this.recordId})
        .then(result=>{    
            let objStr = JSON.parse(result);      
            let listOfFields = JSON.parse(Object.values(objStr)[1]);
            let listOfRecords = JSON.parse(Object.values(objStr)[0]);

            let items = [];

            listOfFields.map(element=>{
                items = [...items ,{label: element.label, fieldName: element.fieldPath}];
            });

            this.columns = items; 
            this.records = listOfRecords; 
            this.totalRecords = listOfRecords.length;
            this.pageSize = this.pageSizeOptions[0];
            this.paginationHelper();
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log('error',error);
            this.records = undefined;
        })

        getRelatedFieldsAndRecords({negotiationId: this.recordId})
        .then(result=>{    
            let objSelectedStr = JSON.parse(result);      
            let listOfSelectedFields = JSON.parse(Object.values(objSelectedStr)[1]);
            let listOfSelectedRecords = JSON.parse(Object.values(objSelectedStr)[0]);

            let items = [];

            listOfSelectedFields.map(element=>{
                items = [...items ,{label: element.label, fieldName: element.fieldPath}];
            });

            this.selectedColumns = items; 
            this.selectedRecords = listOfSelectedRecords; 
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log('error',error);
            this.selectedRecords = undefined;
        })
    }
```

LWC Component:

[image: LWC Component shows ID instead of Name]

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you use Database.Query() to query dynamically to get records however To get relationship fields you need to provide the actual reference for that field.

refer this example

```
String s = 'Select Id, Name, XYZ__r.Name from contact where Id = \'0031D00000KkQLKQA3\'';
System.debug(Database.query(s));

List<Contact> cList = Database.query(s);
for(Contact con : cList){
    system.debug(con.XYZ__r.Name);
}
```

In this above example when we loop through the result in Apex code and access the Name field of the related record, ***you are explicitly requesting the value of that field and the Apex runtime is automatically resolving the relationship for you***. In this case you will get the Actual Name Instead of Id

In your Code you can try like this

```
 List<CLM_Representative__c > lstRecords = Database.query(query);


List<Object> dataTableRecords = new List<Object>();

for(CLM_Representative__c obj : lstRecords) {

    Map<String, Object> record = new Map<String, Object>();

    record.put('Id', obj.Id);
    record.put('Account', obj.Account__r.Name); //explicitly requesting value of the field
    record.put('Field1', obj.Field1__c); //any field
    record.put('Field2', obj.Field2__c); //any field
    dataTableRecords.add(record);
}

     //prepare a map which will hold fieldList and recordList and return it
        returnMap.put('FIELD_LIST', JSON.serialize(lstFSMember));
        returnMap.put('RECORD_LIST', JSON.serialize(dataTableRecords));

        return JSON.serialize(returnMap);
```

**Note**
This above code is an example how we can explicitly request relationship field please feel free to debug and make changes

some reference

[Get SOQL Query to get Account's Name Instead of the Id?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287585/get-soql-query-to-get-accounts-name-instead-of-the-id?rq=1)

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IHlNQAW&_ga=2.25373876.88093845.1675885910-1372243647.1645281567